# PHP Simple HTML DOM parser: excluding tags

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need to exclude a

```
img
```

tag from

```
 <a href="http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx">
     <img style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" 
          src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/xxxxx/xxxxx.jpg">
      Matt Cartledge
 </a>
```

and get only the text i.e. Matt Carledge. Is it possitble using php simple html dom parser?
Thnk you.

```
$first_anchor = $list->find('a',0);
$prof_img = $first_anchor->find('img',0)->src;
echo $prof_name = $first_anchor->innertext;die();
```

i need prof_name to be "Matt Cartledge".

Comment: Should be.  Show us what you've tried, and then we can help you go from there.

Comment: ok please view the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah got it, its ->plaintext; thnk you

If we use like $something->innertext;(It gives everthing inside $something including all tags within it) AND if we use $something->plaintext;(It give only the texts exluding the tags).

Comment: Elaborate so that this could help future users.

Comment: oh.. if we use like $something->innertext;(It gives everthing inside $something including all tags within it) AND if we use $something->plaintext;(It give only the texts exluding the tags).